# loop over list of dictionaries conditional on the key existing

Tags: python, loops

I'm looping over a list of dictionaries in Python, but a few of the dictionaries don't contain a key that most have. For such cases, I'd like the loop to conduct a different operation (say print 'key not found').

```
dict_list = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a': 4}]
dict_list

for i in dict_list:
    print(i['b'])
```

This gives me `KeyError: 'b'`. How do I introduce an operation conditional on the key existing?

Comment: The simple answer is "just do it." I'd suggest writing a function to handle each entry. You can explicitly check if 'key' in i or you can handle KeyError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to catch the exception:

```
for i in dict_list:
    try:
        print(i['b'])
    except KeyError:
        print("key not found")
```

Another is to check the key before using it:

```
for i in dict_list:
    if 'b' in i:
        print(i['b'])
    else:
        print("key not found")
```

Yet another is to use `.get` with a default:

```
for i in dict_list:
    print(i.get('b', "key not found"))
```

Comment: Answers that expand on multiple methods to achieve the same thing are always great for the poster to understand and figure out what is the best method for his/her situation. +1

Comment: [@Felipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305461/felipe), ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ;)

Answer (score 2):

It throws it `KeyError: 'b'` the second index of list (second dict) does not contain `b`.

You can use try-except for "operation conditional on the key existing":

```py
dict_list = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' :4}]


for i in dict_list:
    try:
        # this will print `b` when it founds
        print(i['b'])
    except KeyError:
        # this will be printed when it could not found b
        print('b not found')
```